What is a correct translation for the Greek in Deut 6:4
https://biblebento.com/index.html?lxx1i&50.6.4

I see a translation for the Greek Deutoronomy 6:4 that omits many of the words. It doesn't seem a good translation, "Hear O' Israel: the LORD our God, the LORD is one." That suffices for the Hebrew Masoretic, but it doesn't suffice for the Septuagint.  Can anyone out there offer a faithful translation to the Greek?

The famous "Shema" of Deut 6:4 is tricky to translate to English because of the subtleties of the Hebrew.  Here is my attempt:

Hear, Israel, Yahweh our God, Yahweh is one.

The Septuagint translates it thus:

Ἄκουε, Ἰσραήλ· Κύριος ὁ θεὸς ἡμῶν Κύριος εἷς ἐστιν·

This same translation is quoted, verbatim, in Mark 12:29 which I would translate very literally:

Hear Israel, the Lord our God, [the] Lord is one. // or // Hear Israel, the Lord our God is one Lord. [Both are grammatically possible.]

Now, the "extra words" in the LXX depend on which Septuagint one reads. here are three different versions:
Elpenor, with translation by L.C.L. Brenton:

῎Ακουε, ᾿Ισραήλ· Κύριος ὁ Θεὸς ἡμῶν Κύριος εἷς ἐστι· [- same as above]

Rahlf's and Swete's edition:

Καὶ ταῦτα τὰ δικαιώματα καὶ τὰ κρίματα ὅσα ἐνετείλατο Κύριος τοῖς
υἱοῖς Ἰσραήλ, ἐξελθόντων αὐτῶν ἐκ γῆς Αἰγύπτου Ἄκουε, Ἰσραήλ· Κύριος ὁ
θεὸς ἡμῶν Κύριος εἷς ἐστιν·

This is simply a difference in verse division - the extra text is placed as part of V3 by Elpenor and Brenton.  I would translate this text as:

and these [are] the ordinances, and the judgments, which the Lord
commanded the sons of Israel [when] they had gone out from the land
of Egypt. Hear, O Israel, The Lord our God [the] Lord is one//is one Lord//.


Oh wow. Thanks for the detailed answer. I have a followup question though. If it really translates to the Lord is ONE, then why choose the word "eimi?" From my understanding Jesus said before Abraham was "eimi," which is translated "I am."

@DanielRoth - the verb "eimi" is simply the equivalent of the English verb "to be"; ie, "God is One".  The "is" is part of the verb "to be".  Now, about YHWH being the "I Am" is thus part of the same verb.  Jesus claimed to be the "I am" of Gen 3:14, 15.

Thank you very much for your gracious response. The reason I ask is because my Jewish family and friends use the Shema to try and disprove Jesus. The Septuagint could have used the word eis instead of eimi in Deut 6:4, but they chose eimi instead. Wouldn't  it be better translated, "The LORD is the eternal?"

And looking at yod hey vav hey, could we make the parallel to the Alpha and the Omega whom John refers to in Revelation, considering vav often means and in Hebrew? YH and H, Alpha and Omega?

@DanielRoth - true - the Hebrew in Deut 6:4 could be translated only as "YHWH is one", which is precisely what Christians say about God (as does the NT).

There's 1 Cor. 8:6.  Drop the subordinate clauses and you have,  εἷς θεὸς ὁ πατήρ...καὶ εἷς κύριος Ἰησοῦς Χριστός.  Any Jew reading that would have immediately thought of the Shema.  And, Paul deals with idols here.  So, since there's only one God, do we have "God the Father; Christ Jesus the idol"?  (!!!)  Or, do we have Paul bringing the Shema into play as the foundational doctrine for how we are to live in an idol worshiping world, connecting the Christ to that Shema?  In other words, the divinity of Christ is critical when dealing with idols.  Otherwise, why mention the Christ?

“Hear, O Israel, Jehovah our God is one Jehovah” (Deut 6:4). “And Jehovah God said, Behold! The man has become as one of Us” (Gen 3:22). No interpretations!

Apparently the LXX includes commentary in this verse.  I put the commentary in square brackets. The rest is a good translation. Because of how Hebrew expresses the present tense, there are various ways to translate this verse.

[Καὶ ταῦτα τὰ δικαιώματα καὶ τὰ κρίματα, ὅσα ἐνετείλατο κύριος τοῖς υἱοῖς Ισραηλ ἐν τῇ ἐρήμῳ ἐξελθόντων αὐτῶν ἐκ γῆς Αἰγύπτου] Ἄκουε, Ισραηλ, κύριος ὁ θεὸς ἡμῶν κύριος εἷς ἐστιν, ... -- Septuaginta: With morphology (electronic ed., Deut. 6:4). (1979). Deutsche Bibelgesellschaft.


Hear, O Israel! The LORD is our God, the LORD is one!
(Deut. 6:4, NASB1986)


Hear, O Israel: The LORD our God is one LORD:
(Deut. 6:4, KJV)


שְׁמַ֖ע‬ יִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל יְהוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֵ֖ינוּ יְהוָ֥ה׀ אֶחָֽד׃
--
Elliger, K., Rudolph, W., & Weil, G. E. (2003). Biblia Hebraica Stuttgartensia (electronic ed., Deut. 6:4). German Bible Society.

